# Pubnub IOS app example?

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, swift, pubnub

I have recently started development of an app that uses [PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/) to stream video from Android devices to a web page. What i need to do now is the same thing for IOS.

The [PubNub SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/pubnub-objective-c-sdk-v4) has some basic information regarding IOS development. I was wondering is anyone knows of a [similar example app like they have for the Android version](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-10-13-build-android-webrtc-video-voice-chat-app/)

Comment: https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/252/does-pubnub-support-webrtc-and-video-chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently is no iOS WebRTC sample app. PubNub only plays the role of *signal protocol* in the AndroidRTC and WebRTC Sample apps so it should be relatively easy to follow those apps to create an iOS version.

For more information about the role that PubNub plays in video streaming/chat/WebRTC type apps, please see [What sort of services does PubNub provide with respect to WebRTC and video chat?](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/252/does-pubnub-support-webrtc-and-video-chat)